# Python: Removing vertical and horizontal lines in google vision api

Tags: python, ocr, google-vision

I am trying to extract handwritten text from:

[image]

using https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting

Without using any third party technology, is there any option in Google vision API to remove vertical and horizontal lines from the image before extracting the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hahaha I literally did the exact same thing like 2 months ago.
No, the Vision API can't do this.
Here's how I did it:

1) create an image object with the Python PILLOW library.

2) Get the matrix representation of the image.

3) binarise the matrix.

4) Loop through it line by line and row by row. When you encounter a black pixel, start a counter. If you encounter a white pixel, reset the counter. If the counter goes higher than some high number, conclude that it is a line.

5) Change the black pixels in the line to white pixels.

6) Use Pillow to get a PNG back again.

Comment: That's a great option! Can you please show demo code? I couldn't do it right.